# What service reads /etc/security/access.conf?

Tags: linux, centos, cron, login

I'm trying to get to the bottom of an issue with a non-root user running a cron job and I've stumbled upon `/etc/security/access.conf`. I have a couple of questions:

- What service reads this file?
- Do I need to restart anything after editing it?
- How do I know it's even being used?

Thanks

Comment: what error messages are you seeing from your cron job ?

Answer (score 5):

To see which PAM-based services are using it:

```
grep pam_access /etc/pam.d/*
```

If it's not mentioned in `/etc/pam.d/cron` (which I suspect it won't be) then it shouldn't be having any effect on cron jobs. If there are any `@include` directives in the `pam.d` files, follow them to make sure you don't miss anything.

Comment: In `/etc/pam.d/crond` there's this line: `account    required   pam_access.so` - what does that mean? Thanks

Comment: It means my guess was wrong and your cron is configured to use the `access` module. So `/etc/security/access.conf` will apply.

Comment: And to answer the other question 'do I need to restart anything after editing it?'; No, you do not. The file is read every time a session is opened (in your case, when a cron job runs).

Answer (score 4):

[1] What service reads this file?
It is used by pam

```
[chida@localhost ~]$ rpm -qf /etc/security/access.conf 
pam-1.1.5-7.fc17.x86_64
```

[2] Do I need to restart anything after editing it?

Nothing to restart. Once changed, on subsequent login event, the file is read.

[3] How do I know it's even being used?

```
$ stat /etc/security/access.conf
```

For more details, do man access.conf.

Comment: `stat /etc/security/access.conf` shows `Access: 2012-08-15 08:35:01.762992895 +0000` - what causes the Access timestamp to be altered? It wasn't altered when I ran `cat /etc/security/access.conf`, which must involve reading/accessing the file, right? I'm confused about that.

Comment: Linux doesn't do access timestamps correctly anymore, unless you beg for them with the `strictatime` mount option.

Answer (score 2):

The other two answers are very good, but miss something I wish I understood yesterday.

Access.conf is indeed used by pam_access.so, but so what?  You really need to know if pam_access.so is being used during login.  Check for it here:

```
# grep pam_access.so /etc/pam.d/*-auth
/etc/pam.d/fingerprint-auth:account     required      pam_access.so
/etc/pam.d/password-auth:account     required      pam_access.so
/etc/pam.d/smartcard-auth:account     required      pam_access.so
/etc/pam.d/system-auth:account     required      pam_access.so
```

Here is the thing:  Do not edit these files to add/remove pam_access.so.  Other services may overwrite those changes.  You have to dive into the dark arts of authentication to change these things... doing so without full understanding can lead to a burned tush.

But the others are correct:  changes to access.conf are immediate, requiring no reboot nor service restart.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to add pam_access.so to /etc/pam.d/login and /etc/pam.d/sshd and neither did anything, but this showed me where I needed to put it apparently.

Comment: **authselect** should be used to configure PAM at least on [RHEL 8](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_authentication_and_authorization_in_rhel/configuring-user-authentication-using-authselect_configuring-authentication-and-authorization-in-rhel) and [Fedora 36](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Make_Authselect_Mandatory).